# Althought I specify one expression sql gives "Only one expression can be specified error"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
    DS.SOURCE_TYPE,
    (SELECT  
         I_MAX_VADE,
         CASE 
            WHEN (PA.ACTOR_KIND = 5 AND PA.PROCESS_ID = PROCESS_ID) 
               THEN 0 
               ELSE I_MAX_VADE 
         END   
     FROM 
         KDS_INTER_FAKTORING_OMDM_PARAMS 
     WHERE 
         PA.ID = PROCESS_ACTOR_ID) AS TERER
FROM             
    dbo.PROCESS_ACTOR AS PA  
JOIN
    dbo.OMDM_RESULT AS O ON O.PROCESS_ID = PA.PROCESS_ID
JOIN 
    dbo.KDS_PROPOSAL_OMDM_PARAMS AS POP ON POP.PROCESS_ID = PA.PROCESS_ID
JOIN 
    dbo.PROPOSAL_SNAP AS PS ON PS.PROCESS_ID = PA.PROCESS_ID
JOIN 
    dbo.DEBTOR_SNAP AS DS ON DS.PROCESS_ID = PA.PROCESS_ID
```

This  simple query throws the error specified below.

I think I have already selected one column in my subquery. I would like to assign I_MAX_VADE to its db value.

```
if (PA.ACTOR_KIND = 5 AND PA.PROCESS_ID = PROCESS_ID) else zero.
```

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery `select` returns two columns: `I_MAX_VADE` and the result of the `CASE` expression. That is one too many.

Answer (score 2):

Use `OUTER APPLY`.  It is like a correlated subquery (sometimes) but it is in the `FROM` clause rather than the `SELECT`.  And, you can have as many columns as you like:

```
SELECT . . .,
       DS.SOURCE_TYPE,
       params.*
FROM dbo.PROCESS_ACTOR PA  JOIN
     dbo.OMDM_RESULT O
     ON O.PROCESS_ID = PA.PROCESS_ID JOIN
     dbo.KDS_PROPOSAL_OMDM_PARAMS POP
     ON POP.PROCESS_ID = PA.PROCESS_ID JOIN
     dbo.PROPOSAL_SNAP PS
     ON PS.PROCESS_ID = PA.PROCESS_ID JOIN
     dbo.DEBTOR_SNAP DS
     ON DS.PROCESS_ID = PA.PROCESS_ID OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT I_MAX_VADE,
             (CASE WHEN PA.ACTOR_KIND = 5 AND PA.PROCESS_ID = params.PROCESS_ID THEN 0 
                   ELSE params.I_MAX_VADE
              END) as TERER 
       FROM KDS_INTER_FAKTORING_OMDM_PARAMS params
       WHERE PA.ID = params.PROCESS_ACTOR_ID
     ) params
```

Note:  I had to guess at the source of a couple columns.  You should always qualify column names -- and this is even more important when you are using correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to answer from HABO, but I'll add an example:

**WRONG:**

```
SELECT A, B, (SELECT X, Y FROM MyTable) AS C
FROM OtherTable
```

When you put a subquery into your select-list, the subquery must be a *scalar subquery*; i.e. it must be guaranteed to return one column and one row.

The example above is wrong because the subquery returns two columns, and it is not necessarily going to return a single row.

**RIGHT:**

```
SELECT A, B, (SELECT TOP 1 X FROM MyTable) AS C
FROM OtherTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out how I can accomplish my task.Here is my updated code.

I simply remove my column(I_MAX_VADE) from select case and insert it into then clause.

**

### Before

**

```
(SELECT  
         I_MAX_VADE,
         CASE 
            WHEN (PA.ACTOR_KIND = 5 AND PA.PROCESS_ID = PROCESS_ID) 
               THEN 0 
               ELSE I_MAX_VADE 
         END   
     FROM 
         KDS_INTER_FAKTORING_OMDM_PARAMS 
     WHERE 
         PA.ID = PROCESS_ACTOR_ID) AS TERER
```

**

### After

**

```
(SELECT 
(CASE 
WHEN (PA.ACTOR_KIND=5) 
THEN (SELECT I_MAX_VADE FROM KDS_INTER_FAKTORING_OMDM_PARAMS 
WHERE PA.ID=PROCESS_ACTOR_ID )
ELSE 0 END) ) AS TERER
```